# Use multiple contexts with same user-name in kubectl config

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to use multiple clusters with my `kubectl` so I either put everything into one config or add one config file per cluster to the `KUBECONFIG` env variable. That's all fine.

My problem is now, that I've users with the same user-name for each cluster but they use different `client-key-data` for each cluster (context) but somehow the context uses that user-name so it's not clear which user belongs to which cluster.

Better give an example:

Cluster 1:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://10.11.12.13:8888
  name: team-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: team-cluster
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@team-cluster
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: XXYYYZZZ
    client-key-data: XXXYYYZZZ
```

Cluster 2:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://10.11.12.14:8888
  name: dev-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: dev-cluster
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@dev-cluster
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: AABBCC
    client-key-data: AABBCC
```

As you see, in both cluster there's a user with name `kubernetes-admin` but from the context it's not clear which of those. Maybe there's another way to give it a unique identifier that is used by the context.

Maybe the solution is obvious but I've not found any example for such a case. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you put everything in the config file and tried to change the current-context (`kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name `) ?

Comment: I use two config files which are added to KUBECONFIG env var (`KUBECONFIG="$HOME/.kube/config:$HOME/.kube/config-dev:$HOME/.kube/config-team"`) and then switch context using `kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@team-cluster` for example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had same issue with my config and found out that name in users is not username used to log in - its just name used to identify user section in config. In Your case only cert key is used to know who You are. So You can use:

```
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: AABBCC
    client-key-data: AABBCC
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate-data: XXYYYZZZ
    client-key-data: XXXYYYZZZ
```

and refer to that in context just by key:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: dev-cluster
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
```

Full config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://10.11.12.13:8888
  name: team-cluster
- cluster:
    server: https://10.11.12.14:8888
  name: dev-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: team-cluster
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
  name: kubernetes-admin@team-cluster
- context:
    cluster: dev-cluster
    user: kubernetes-admin-2
  name: kubernetes-admin@dev-cluster
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: XXYYYZZZ
    client-key-data: XXXYYYZZZ
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate-data: AABBCC
    client-key-data: AABBCC
```

For auth methods that require username it's used something like this:

```
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-with-password
  user:
    username: kubernetes-admin
    password: mySecretPass
```

Using more than one kubeconfig is not much comfortable - you need to specify them for each command. You can have as much contexts and users if You want in one config and select right context (and save selected context as default).

Answer (score 1):

User in kubeconfig doesn't matter it is used as a reference for respective context. actually the common-name(CN) from client cert being used for authorization.

Working config: (i copied all clusters ca,certs and keys to $HOME/pki dir)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
current-context: "c1"
preferences: {}
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: ../pki/c1_ca.pem
    server: https://20.100.1.10:6443
  name: c1
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: ../pki/c2_ca.pem
    server: https://20.100.1.8:6443
  name: c2
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: ../pki/c3_ca.pem
    server: https://20.100.1.11:6443
  name: c3
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: c1
    namespace: default
    user: c1
  name: c1
- context:
    cluster: c2
    namespace: default
    user: c2
  name: c2
- context:
    cluster: c3
    namespace: default
    user: c3
  name: c3
users:
- name: c1
  user:
    client-certificate: ../pki/c1_client_cert.pem
    client-key: ../pki/c1_client_key.pem
- name: c2
  user:
    client-certificate: ../pki/c2_client_cert.pem
    client-key: ../pki/c2_client_key.pem
- name: c3
  user:
    client-certificate: ../pki/c3_client_cert.pem
    client-key: ../pki/c3_client_key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple kubeconfig files in the `KUBECONFIG` variable, then kubectl internally merges them before usage (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable)). So, if you have two users with the same name in your kubeconfig files, they will probably override each other and you get either one or the other.

The solution is to either use different names for the users in the various kubeconfig files, or to explicitly specify one of the kubeconfig files, e.g. `kubectl --kubeconfig dev-cluster.conf` or having only a single kubeconfig file in the `KUBECONFIG` variable at a time.

In general, I would recommend the first approach and use a unique name for each different set of credentials (i.e. user) across your entire local configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that was kind of obvious. I renamed the `users.name` to give every context a unique user. Now it works as expected.I wasn't aware that the configs will be merged.